# Eloquent - combining User::where with Hash::check

Tags: laravel, eloquent, lumen

I am using Lumen/Laravel Eloquent.

I have table ***users*** with column ***token*** which represents hashed token value created with Hash::make($fullToken).

Now I want to compare full token value which users sends from to server with hashed value saved into database.

I am not able to do this this way:

```
$hashedToken = Hash::make($userSentToken);
```

because each hashed value has *salt* part and I need to use Eloquent's Hash::check('plain-text', $hashedValue) function.

How can I combine this check() method with User::where() ?

I want unique way to convert that full token to hashed value and to select token column from database by that hashed value.

Answer (score 0):

**Why not `Hash`**

`Hash::make` returns different output every call, but you need a deterministic function. `Hash::make` is not a simple deterministic function like `md5` which returns constant output at every given input. So you can't query hash when using `Hash` facade the way you've described.

If you need to query a hashed value through a database, try to use smth like an `md5` function instead of `Hash::make`.

**Some variants to store**

- `md5($userSentToken)`
- `md5($userSentToken . $salt)`
- `md5(md5($userSentToken))`